# How can i combine columns and row like this

Tags: pandas

[image]

My English not very well!!

how can I do that?

please help

Comment: You probably need to melt the data `pd.melt` is one option then you can concatenate the columns. Also please don't post pictures, Use text much as you can while you ask questions, this way your example can be reproduced. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Firstly use `melt()` method:-

```
df=df.melt(id_vars='Years')

#output of above code

    Years   variable    value
0   2011    Q1          63,3259
1   2010    Q1          45,8989
2   2012    Q1          69,9696
3   2013    Q1          80,0000
4   2011    Q2          96,3259
```

**Step 2:**

Then sort values by using `sort_values()` method:

```
df=df.sort_values(['Years'],ignore_index=True)
```

**Step 3:**

Finally:-

```
df['data']=df['Years'].astype(str)+'-'+df['variable']
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output

```
    Years   variable    value       data
0   2010    Q1          45,8989     2010-Q1
1   2010    Q2          42,8989     2010-Q2
2   2010    Q3          88,8989     2010-Q3
3   2010    Q4          45,8989     2010-Q4
4   2011    Q1          63,3259     2011-Q1
5   2011    Q2          96,3259     2011-Q2
6   2011    Q3          23,3259     2011-Q3
7   2011    Q4          63,3259     2011-Q4
```

Comment: You got your expected result?

Comment: No. ı got a problem. what should i do write in 'variable' my data

Comment: Edited answer kindly have a look

Comment: It's clear now but I still haven't fully solve, its going to q1 q1 q1, it should q1-q2-q3-q4-q1-q2-q3-q4.

Comment: Edited my answer...Kindly have a look

Comment: Unfornately it is not going to q1 q2 q3 q4 it sorting 'values' by column. I think -melt it's not enough to that.

Comment: **Follow along with steps** from **beginning**....I edited my answer now you will get it